How to Call aggFunc from AG-Grid API?
I can see AggFunc is calling when column grouping is done, however it is not calling in the initial load. I am looking for calling aggFunc from gridAPI, can someone guide me to it?

please share the minimal reproducible code, along with steps explaining the issue and what needs fixing
